# Wrap post thumbnail with <figure>

Tags: post-thumbnails

I'd like to wrap my post thumbnail with `<figure>` tags.

I have tried the following and the image appears, but the `<figure>` tags come up empty.

```
<?php
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    echo '<figure>'.the_post_thumbnail('gallery').'</figure>';
}
?>
```

I've also tried the following, but the image is missing and only the empty `<figure>` tags appear.

```
<?php
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    echo '<figure>'.get_the_post_thumbnail('gallery').'</figure>';
}
?>
```

**UPDATE**

For anyone wanting the full code from the answer, here it is:

```
<?php
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    echo '<figure>'.get_the_post_thumbnail( $page->ID, 'gallery').'</figure>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [get_the_post_thumbnail( $id, $size )](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/)
if you're going to echo the result.

And make sure you have post thumbs enabled.

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

Comment: This didn't work unfortunately. I've updated my question to reflect your suggestion.

Comment: You're missing the post/post id. Read the codex

Answer (score 0):

The feature became available with Version 2.9. Note that you can optionally pass a second argument with an array of the Post Types for which you want to enable this feature.

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post' ) );          // Posts only
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'page' ) );          // Pages only
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post', 'movie' ) ); // Posts and Movies
```

This feature must be called before the init hook is fired. That means it needs to be placed directly into *functions.php* or within a function attached to the '`after_setup_theme`' hook.

**NOTE**: For custom post types, you can also add post thumbnails using the `register_post_type` function as well.